# How to connect from mobile phone to the localhost

Tags: django, mobile, localhost, wifi

I am developing a website on Django, the local version is run by development server (`python manage.py runserver`) on localhost. I can test my site in a browser, the address is http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

But now I need to see how my website is looking on the mobile phone. My laptop OS is Linux Mint, the phone OS is Android, both are connected to the WiFi router.

I tried this [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device). I found out my WLAN IP (by the command `ifconfig`), which happens to be 192.168.0.104. By the recipe, I should enter the address together with port number, which is, apparently, 8000 (according to the development server port, see the paragraph 1), so I should see my local website by the address 192.168.0.104:8000, both from the laptop and the phone browser.
However, in both devices I get a following error (translated to English):

> Can not connect. Firefox cannot establish a connection to the server
> at 192.168.0.104:8000. The site may be temporarily unavailable or too
> busy. Please try again in a few moments. If you cannot load any pages,
> check your computer's network connection. If your computer or network
> is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure Firefox has permission
> to access the web.

From the phone the error is similar:

> This site can't be reached. 192.168.0.104 refused to connect. Try:
> checking the connection. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

From this I conclude, that

1. the address exists, but my device doesn't let me see it;
2. the problem is not with the phone, it is somewhere in my laptop.

Here I stuck. There are three possible reasons in my mind:

1. Linux firewall. I tried to disable it, but the result was the same;
2. server settings. Here I'm lost. As I understand, I use Django `runserver`. But, interestingly, if I type on my phone only the IP without the port, I see the  Apache2 Default Page. Suspect that my router can be working on its own Apache (?).
3. router settings. Also I don't know where the problem could be.

Please help me with any ideas how to connect to the `localhost` from my phone. So far, I have to upload any tiny change on the deployment server and see my website from the phone through in the internet, which is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngrok` to serve your project. connect `ngrok` to your project `port` and enter anywhere you want. for more read **[docs](https://ngrok.com/docs)**

Comment: Thanks, turalmehrali! I will give it a try. Although I hoped there's a more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

add this `0.0.0.0:8000` to your runserver command.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And dev server should accept external request.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#examples-of-using-different-ports-and-addresses